# how to resolve my unit test issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to build unit test for my case

I have something in my controller like

```
$scope.getDetail = function(name) {
    //other codes
    //using testFactory to get details
    testFactory.getDetail(name).then(function(detail){
        console.log(detail)
    })
    //other codes
}
```

Factory file

```
var factory = {};
factory.getDetail = function(name) {
    //calculate…etc
    return details;
}
return factory;
```

Unit test file

```
describe('controller', function () {
    var testCtrl, scope, testFactory;
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _testFactory_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        testFactory = _testFactory_;

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    };

        var name = 'test';
        spyOn(testFactory, 'getDetail').and.callFake(function(name) {
            return 'success';
        });

         it('should get details', function() {
            var result =  testFactory.getDetail(name);
            expect(result).toBeTruthy(); 
        })
    }));
```

I am getting

```
undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'testFactory.getDetail(name)' error.
```

Can anyone help me to solve this? Not sure what went wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like `getDetail` is returning `details`, which is perhaps not a promise as expected by the controller.

Comment: Seem like you got problems with `callFake` `testFactory` and position of your **second** `beforeEach` block. It should not contains `it` block. One more thing, you should put `spyOn` inside your `beforeEach` block or `it` block. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/dueowr60/)